# DateTime.Now Not Updating C#

Tags: c#, datetime, console

I have this simple time program that uses `DateTime.Now`, it part of a bigger program I have but this is just a small error I notice. I made a TimeStamp string to get the time of whenever something was done in the code and sending to the console. However, its not updating? I swear at one point it did work and was updating but then it stopped, am I missing something?

p.s I dont need the seconds but I put it there for testing purposes, I have also tried it with `DateTime.UtcNow` and it still didn't work

Code

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Threading.Tasks;

namespace ConsoleApp1TimeStampNEW
{
    internal class Program
    {
        private static DateTime Now = DateTime.Now;

        static string strDate = Now.ToString("MM/dd/yyyy");
        static string timeString = DateTime.Now.ToString("hh:mm ss tt");
        static string TIMESTAMP = strDate + " " + timeString + " ";

        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            char input;

            do
            {
                Console.WriteLine("\n"+TIMESTAMP);
                Console.WriteLine("\nWould you like to repeat? Y/N");

                input = Convert.ToChar(Console.ReadLine());
            }
            while (input == 'y');

            Console.WriteLine("\nPress any key to exit.");
            Console.ReadKey();
        }
    }
}
```

Output

```
08/30/2022 12:57 58 PM

Would you like to repeat? Y/N
y

08/30/2022 12:57 58 PM

Would you like to repeat? Y/N
```

Comment: You are creating a string variable named `TIMESTAMP` that has a value set at the time of instantiation. It doesn't change after that point. Replace `Console.WriteLine("\n"+TIMESTAMP);` with `Console.WriteLine("\n"+ DateTime.Now.ToString("MM/dd/yyyy hh:mm:ss tt"));` which will then make your program get the `DateTime.Now` each time the loop is repeated, instead of just referencing the string you originally created.

Comment: But don't actually do that.  Instead, change your `static` declarations from variable (which store one value) to property getters (which run code each time they are used).  All you need to change in your source code is from `=` to `=>` for the four `static` declarations `Now`, `strDate`, `timeString`, and `TIMESTAMP`.

Comment: @BenVoigt What's the point in creating any of those static declarations when `DateTime.Now` is already a static call you can make?

Comment: @MidnightBlueKnight No idea without the code you originally had. It's possible you were declaring your string variables inside of the loop originally.

Comment: @Ibrennan208: Maybe someday the code needs to use time from a network server, instead of `DateTime.Now`.  Wouldn't it be better to have just one place to update?  (More realistically -- during test execution, the system clock needs to be mocked)  Maybe the timestamp format might need to change, to adhere to a certain logfile format.  Wouldn't it be better to change only one place?

Comment: Agreed, but in this case it doesn't appear to be that complex of an issue, and may lead to more confusion during the asker's learning journey. At the current point they don't know how to make static calls, so it's unlikely that they are understanding everything you are saying which will lead to more confusion down the line.

Comment: The idea is that we would be over-complicating a basic command line program that someone is trying to learn from. I definitely agree with you on what you are saying, but think the program we are looking at is not yet at that level.

Comment: @MidnightBlueKnight Here is a fiddle that shows how it could be achieved with both methods mentioned: https://dotnetfiddle.net/rcdX53 (Notice the different method for parsing `char` as well. This is to avoid any exceptions when the user enters more than one character or something that cannot be converted to a character. Read more about that here: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.char.tryparse?view=net-6.0)

Comment: @Ibrennan208 geez i was making this more complicated then i needed it thanks!

Answer (score 1):

`TIMESTAMP` is just a string. Once you set it, there is no relationship to the `DateTime` type.

You want something more like this:

```
do
{
    Console.WriteLine($"\n{DateTime.Now:MM/dd/yyyy hh:mm:ss tt}");
    Console.WriteLine("\nWould you like to repeat? Y/N");

    input = Console.ReadLine()[0];
}
while (input == 'y');
```

---

If you want a string value formatted a certain way every time you use it, one way is via a **property**:

```
public string TIMESTAMP {get { return DateTime.Now.ToString("MM/dd/yyyy hh:mm:ss tt"); } }
```

Of course, this needs to be in a class somewhere, but then you could use it like this, which looks more like the original code:

```
do
{
    Console.WriteLine($"\n" + myClass.TIMESTAMP);
    Console.WriteLine("\nWould you like to repeat? Y/N");

    input = Console.ReadLine()[0];
}
while (input == 'y');
```

And of course, a method can do the same thing, but for some reason this just feels like a property fits more what you are trying to do.

Comment: No need to throw away the abstraction layer and start hard-coding format strings throughout the program.

Comment: @BenVoigt No need to add redundant layers of abstraction, when you can make the static call directly on the class itself.

Comment: If anything, the format string could be stored in a variable, and in a larger program it could have a property getter that accesses the timestamp, but as it stands this program is too simple and it adds complexity that may confuse the asker.

Comment: @Ibrennan208 You make a lot of great points. In my larger program there is so much extra details that wasn't needed so I made this small program to zero in on the problem. I liked having my TIMESTAMP as a string variable at the time bc at the time it was easier and in one location. I call the TIMSTAMP string over +20 times in my program. I like ben-voigt solution bc it let me continue to how the code worked before without having to look through 10,000 lines of code.

Comment: Yes definitely go with that solution if you have that many lines of code haha, glad it is working for you now.

Answer (score 0):

Try something like this

```
public string TIMESTAMP {get {return DateTime.Now.ToString();} };
```

Every time you use TIMESTAMP it will get the current date and time and return it as a string.